# Running Vagrant 1.2.2 on VirtualBox in the Terminal would get the machine stuck in debian-login

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, vagrant, vagrantfile

I am currently setting up Vagrant 1.2.2 on my Mac OS X 10.9.2 using VirtualBox.

Using the command `vagrant up` under my `dev/official` directory, I would get this issue: VirtualBox would boot vagrant up, but it would be stuck on this screen:

```
Debian GNU/Linux 7 vagrant-debian tty1

vagrant-debian login:
```

When it times out, it will give me a SSH error.

This only happens when I boot the machine up via the Terminal, since with the GUI, I can put in the login credentials `vagrant` and `vagrant` for username and password respectively. I do not want to use the GUI; I want to use the Terminal to automatically log me into the machine.

What I tried is, I point vagrant to my private key using this within `Vagrantfile`:

```
  Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
   config.ssh.private_key_path = "~/.ssh/github_rsa"
   config.ssh.forward_agent = true
  end
```

`~/.ssh/github_rsa` is the extension to my private key. When I check `vagrant ssh-config`, I noticed the `IdentityFile` points to `IdentityFile "/Users/my_name/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key"`, which is not the right private key. What I did to try to solve this issue was manually copy my `github_rsa` private key to that directory (and naming the old one to `insecure_private_key_old`). That did not solve an issue, and instead, actually gave me another issue:

`/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.6.7/lib/net/ssh/key_factory.rb:77:in`read': Could not parse PKey: no start line (ArgumentError)`

This is one of the many errors that popped up. Seems to be a gems issue.

I am not quite sure what the issue is, and if anyone of you have encountered this issue before, please let me know.

EDIT: I have tried to uninstall `net-ssh` and installing an older version of `net-ssh` as suggested by a thread I found online by the name "ArgumentError: Could not parse PKey: no start line", but that did not seem to help the issue either.

Comment: I would recommend you fist of all from running the whole thing on update versions of Vagrant. 1.2.2 is from April 2013 which is a lot in Vagrant terms.

Comment: Hi @MichaelS. I need to use 1.2.2 since our virtual machines are configured for that version. It's a bit of a hassle, I understand, but is there anyway to make it work?

Comment: when did you add the private_key_path? before or after you ran `vagrant up`? if you did that after, you need to run `vagrant reload`. also please share debug output of `vagrant ssh --debug`.